# How can I check if an object is in another object (defined by my class)?

Tags: python

How can I check if an object is in another object? So say I have the following defined:

```
class Container:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = ['x','y','z']
```

and I want to be able to make the following work:

```
'x' in Container()  # True
```

My attempt/guess was that there was some type of dunder method for *in* like so:

```
class Container:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = ['x','y','z']
    def __in__(self, item):
        return item in self.a
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this case, the *in* operator relies on the object being iterable. So the solution would be to define the dunder method for *__iter__* as follows:

```
def __iter__(self, item):
    return iter(self.a)
```

For the final product to be:

```
class Container:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = ['x','y','z']
    def __iter__(self, item):
        return iter(self.a)
```

Comment: The [`__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) method is used for iteration and is a backup mechanism for the `in` operator. A more suitable dunder method should be [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__). Please refer to [Membership test operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details).